# Sitefinity website (Front-end) with authentication

Tags: sitefinity

We are using sitefinity 7.3. Front-end is accessible to anyone (annoymous) currently but in one section we need to add authorization (e.g. add a new role called Front-end and assign to users who can access that part of front-end)

E.g. We have 100 pages and out 10 need to be accessible via authorized users only Other 90 anyone can access.

Any idea how we can achieve this?

Please let me know if more information needed on this? 
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You will modify the pages you want to restrict permissions to allow if the role you created view permission for the front end.

Comment: Is there any separate front-end view permission?

Comment: Under permissions for the page you want to restrict, break the inheritance, then set "View this page and its child pages", too whatever is needed

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple way is you can create a Widget call "Login" and drag and drop it on some page you need to be set authorization.

So when the client goes to this page the system will ask for login and if the info input correct system will display the content.

Step 1: Create Page such as "Authorization page".

Step 2: Drag and drop login widget.

Step 3: Implement this widget by UserControl of MVC, it will check the login for it username and switch to the right content.